# How can I select specific columns on knex with join?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, knex.js

I have a comments table with foreign keys that reference both the author and the post where the comment was made. I am trying to pull the comments like so:

```
return knex.table('comments').join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'comments.user_id').where('post_id', id);
```

And I do get the comments for the specified post id, but I also get ALL the columns from the user column, including their email and password hashes:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "post_id": 1,
        "body": "Some random text.",
        "username": "John Doe",
        "email": "johndoe@example.com",
        "password_hash": "edited"
    },

...
]
```

I want to get rid of the email and password_hash columns. Adding pluck() only renders one column. If I add more columns to the .pluck() call, I get an array of booleans. How can I make it so that it only gets the id column from the users table and all of the stuff from the comments table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was severely sleep deprived so I forgot about joins for some reason:

```
getAllComments(id) {
        return knex.select([
            'comments.id',
            'comments.post_id',
            'comments.body',
            'users.username',
        ]).from('comments').innerJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'comments.user_id')
            .where('comments.user_id', '=', id);
    },
```

returns:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "post_id": 1,
    "body": "Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts.",
    "username": "John Doe"
  },

...
]
```